# jQuery/Javascript: 2 function calls in line, wait for the other to finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this might sound silly but I have no idea how to do that …

```
$('#someButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do ajax stuff
    triggerAjaxSubmit('#signUpForm', false);


    modalSlide(modal, $('.loginTab'), $('.saveTab'));
});
```

On click on `#someButton` I want to submit an entire form via ajax. The function that does this is called `triggerAjaxSubmit`. This function has a simple $.ajax() function provided by jquery and does something on either `success` or `error`.

So what I wonder is how I can delay the next line `modalSlide()` until I get a success or error from the `triggerAjaxSubmit()` function. Right now `triggerAjaxSubmit()` gets fired and immediately after it the `modalSlide()` function fires. However I want the `modalSlide()` function only to fire once a success or error comes back.

Can I do that somehow? I mean like `return "success"` inside of the ajax() call and only than fire the `modalSlide()` function?

thank you in advance.
Kind regards,
Matt

edit:

```
   function triggerAjaxSubmit(formId, reset, callback) {

    $(formId).ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        resetForm: reset,
        dataType: "text json",
        success: function(jsonObject, status) {

                // some other stuff

                console.log('success');

        },
        error: function(requestObject, status) {

            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
triggerAjaxSubmit(form, true, function() {
            console.log('this is not happning')
            modalSlide(modal, $('.loginTab, .signUpTab'), $('.saveWeaveTab'), $('#newWeaveForm_title'));
        });
```

Comment: Moving the second function call into the success and error functions is a solution.  Will this work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return the deferred that `$.ajax` returns in `triggerAjaxSubmit`. Something like:

```
function triggerAjaxSubmit( .. ) {
  return $.ajax({ .. });
}
```

and:

```
triggerAjaxSubmit( .. ).done(function() {
  modalSlide( .. );
});
```

---

**Edit:** With the form plugin, you should be able to do this:

```
function triggerAjaxSubmit( .. , callback ) {
  $( .. ).ajaxSubmit({
    .. ,

    success: function() {
      console.log("success");
      callback();
    })
  });
}
```

and:

```
triggerAjaxSubmit( .. , function() {
  modalSlide( .. );
});
```

Comment: Considerably more elegant than my answer, and I learnt something new - +1

Comment: thank you, that would be a solution I'd love to use but it seems in my case this wouldn't work because I use the jquery FormPlugin to submit the form via ajax … see my updated answer … i get an `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'done'`

Comment: @Matt: Looking at the source of `ajaxSubmit`, it looks like it does not return the deferred so there is no way to obtain it. But, the API says "You can pass any of the standard `$.ajax` options to `ajaxSubmit`". Please see my edit.

Comment: thanks again, did I get this right? I updated my question again? Does not work for me right now … I get a success back from the server however the `modalSlide()` function and the `console.log()` call inside the callback function is not fired.

Comment: @Matt: You don't seem to actually use `callback`. You could run `callback()` inside the success handler.

Comment: wow, yes I am dumb. Now I finally got it and it is working. Thank you for making you a hard time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your `modalSlide` function from the callback in your `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are asynchronous (unless you use the questionable `async: false` option in jQuery), so if you want to execute some code when the AJAX request receives a response, you'll need to put it in the `success` callback.

Depending on the rest of your code, this may be as simple as modifying the `triggerAjaxSubmit` function so that the callback supplied to the `$.ajax()` function includes the relevant code.

Or you may need to modify it a bit more to take a function as an argument, which is then provided as the success callback for the `$.ajax()` function.

Edit: I missed the "or error" in the question, hence why I only referred to the `success` callback. Same principle applies for the `error` callback, though.

Answer (score 1):

call `modalSlide` function in `success` parameter of `$.ajax()` call